# Picklist Validation

Tags: validation-rule

i'm trying to get a Validation rule on a pick list here to say as below

Pick list values: Individual, Massive, Assessment Center

If Individual is selected the record can be saved but if either Massive or Assessment Center is selected it should throw an error to populate another field with api "Invoice_amount__c"

```
If(
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Sub_Type__c, "Massive"),
ISPICKVAL(Sub_Type__c, "Assessment Center"),
AND(
Not ISPICKVAL(Sub_Type__c, "Individual"),
ISBLANK(Text(Invoice_amount__c)))), False, True)
```

I'm close i think but missing something...

Comment: IF(OR( ISPICKVAL(Sub_Type__c, "Massive"),ISPICKVAL(Sub_Type__c, "Assessment Center")) ?

If these values are selected then it fires, but not otherwise.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Akarind - you are right if its these 2 values then the validation rule should fire to stop saving record and asking to populate the other field

Comment: Ah i forgot to add ISBLANK(Invoice_amount__c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is to force user to enter Invoice amount only for the 2 picklist values (Massive, Assessment Center), then you can try something like this

```
AND(
  OR(
   ISPICKVAL(Sub_Type__c, "Massive"),
   ISPICKVAL(Sub_Type__c, "Assessment Center")
  ),
  ISBLANK(Text(Invoice_amount__c)
)
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi...your formula works for Massive but bypasses Assessment Center

Comment: can you check if you have used the correct picklist value and its spelling ? the logic is simple & straight forward.

Comment: The Api name was different to the picklist value... changing it made the difference..Thanks for the help